# How to take picture in Android but keep it in memory only

Tags: android, file, memory-management, android-camera

My requirement is to take the picture from the camera in Android, and not to save the picture in a file but rather save it in the memory, so the file is not left behind.

I know one option is to delete the file afterwards, but this is not good enough, I need another level of security so there is no trace left at all. The code below is from "Taking Photos Simply", I have shortened the code for brevity.

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // **Create the File** where the photo should go
        File photoFile = createImageFile();
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(...,...,photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(..., photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }

String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an **image file** name
    return image;
}
```

The point here is that a "File" is required, which I need to do away with. My research so far has led me to create my own ContentProvider like this https://gist.github.com/m039/6550133 "Custom ContentProvider", based on memory array (android). I was hoping for a simpler solution than this. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> My research so far has led me to create my own ContentProvider like this https://gist.github.com/m039/6550133 "Custom ContentProvider", based on memory array (android).

That particular `ContentProvider` example will be of limited use, as virtually nothing in it is relevant for this use case. That being said, having a `ContentProvider` where you stream the results into memory, rather than disk, is your only somewhat-viable solution for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Bear in mind that this approach will not work much of the time, because:

- You may not be able to allocate the memory buffer that you need, particularly since, strictly speaking, you do not know how big it needs to be ahead of time. You could use the camera APIs, find the highest resolution, then use that to size your memory buffer ahead of time, but even then you will run into challenges due to heap fragmentation.
- Not that many camera apps support `content` as a `Uri` scheme at the moment. For example, Google's did not support it until the summer of 2016. By 2018 or so, most camera apps should support `content` (I hope), but even then it will not be 100%.

> I was hoping for a simpler solution than this.

You can work with the camera APIs directly, but that will be more complicated.

I am looking to add [something to help with this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/285) in my CWAC-Cam2 library, though I have not implemented yet as of late 2016.

You could see if there are other camera libraries that support giving you the results in memory.

And that's about it.

Comment: store the file in sd card and then just remove the file after use.